# Allure testNg: adding details to environmental section

Tags: java, testng, environment, allure

In the Environment section of Allure reports, I would like to add UserName [user performing the test], Operating system, Java version, and Host Name to Allure reports. How can this be accomplished using TestNg?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can define the `environment` https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_environment

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks @lucasnguyen17 for prompt response !! However if it was defined in environment.properties as per the documentation. we need to hardcode it in property file. But I need it  to take it in run time for eg:                        
 Browser={Chrome }should be dynamic based on browser I run,, similar case applies to all below properties
Browser.Version=63.0
Stand=Production

Comment: You can add Allure.parameter(name, value);